# Auto Populating a php form

Tags: php, forms, auto-populate

I am trying to create a form with an auto-populate feature where a user enters an employee ID, and fields like name, job title, status, etc populate when they leave the employee ID field, similar to the function of the table in http://www.crackajax.net/popform.php#. The data will later be submitted into another database to track other user-entered information. However, when I assemble the files, I can't seem to get the onchange feature to work. Here are the forms:

The form itself:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

</head>

<body>

    <form id="entry" name="entry" method="post">


            <label for="employeeid" class="stdlabel">Employee ID:</label>
                <input type="text" id="employeeID" name="employeeID" onchange="geteedata()">
        <br>
            <label for="employeename" class="stdlabel">Employee Name:</label>
                <input id ="employeename" type="text" name="employeename">
        <br>
            <label for="employeestatus "class="stdlabel">Status:</label>
                <input type="text" name="employeestatus" >
        <br>
            <label for="employeetitle"class="stdlabel">Job Title:</label>
                <input type="text" name="employeetitle" >
        <br>
            <label for="loccode" class="stdlabel">Employee Loc Code:</label>
                <input type="text" name="loccode" >

    <input type="submit" name ="submit" value="Submit" style="margin-right:10px">
  </form>

 <?php
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "xxx");
        if(!$con) {
            die("Cannot connect to database:" . mysql_error()); 
        }

        mysql_select_db("mydb", $con);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO casetracker (emplid,empname,empjobtitle,status, loccode) VALUES ('$_POST[employeeid]','$_POST[employeename]','$_POST[employeetitle]','$_POST[employeestatus]','$_POST[loccode]')";

        mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_close($con);

    ?>                
</body>

</html>
```

The following is the javascript file:

```
function geteedata() {
var url = "search.inc.php?param=";
var idValue = document.getElementById("employeeID").value;
var myRandom = parseInt(Math.random() * 99999999);  // cache buster
http.open("GET", url + escape(idValue) + "&rand=" + myRandom, true);
http.onreadystatechange = handleHttpResponse;
http.send(null);
}

function handleHttpResponse() {
if (http.readyState == 4) {
results = http.responseText.split(",");
document.getElementById('employeename').value = results[0];
document.getElementById('employeestatus').value = results[1];
document.getElementById('employeetitle').value = results[2];
document.getElementById('loccode').value = results[3];
}
   }
```

And here is search.inc.php:

```
if(strlen($param)>0){
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employee_data WHERE Pernr ='$param'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1) {
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $employeename = $myrow["Last_First"];
   $employeestatus = $myrow["Emp_Status"];
   $employeetitle = $myrow["Position_Text"];
   $loccode = $myrow["loccode"];
   $textout .= $employeename.",".$employeestatus.",".$employeetitle.",".$loccode;
}
} else {
$textout=" , , ,".$param;
}
}
echo $textout;
```

Does anyone have thoughts on what I'm forgetting, missing or doing incorrectly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: jQuery really does simplify AJAX: https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: Do you know which part doesn't work? Is the request going out, but the php isn't returning your expected results?

Comment: Hey Jack. I have tried a few IDs that I know are in the table, but none of the other fields populate.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not creating an instance of the XMLHttpRequest object before sending off the request.

Try the following:

```
function geteedata() {
var url = "search.inc.php?param=";
var idValue = document.getElementById("employeeID").value;
var myRandom = parseInt(Math.random() * 99999999);  // cache buster

var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("GET", url + escape(idValue) + "&rand=" + myRandom, true);
http.onreadystatechange = handleHttpResponse;
http.send(null);
}
```

Have a look at [MDN Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jack. I realized when I went back to my post that I must have cut and pasted the third file incorrectly. I have fixed that in my revised search.inc.php, so I imagine I still have a problem there.

Comment: OK. Just to check though, the code in the javascript file still doesn't initialise the object.